# Анимация css и js

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

подскажите как правильнее сделать анимацию.
есть 7 блоков, нужно их выстроить в 2 ряда: 1-й ряд из 4 блоков одинаковых и 2-й ряд из 3 блоков(3-блок на ширину двух). При нажатии была анимация увеличения блока на всю ширину и высоту родителя и поверх всех остальных примерно как ниже.
Еще чтоб блоки были адаптивны под размер экрана

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block')
blocks.forEach((elem, i) => {
  elem.style.transform = "translateX(" + elem.offsetWidth * i + "px)"
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    elem.classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  background-color: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
  border: 2px solid blue
}

.active {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: translateX(0px) !important;
  height: 600px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

вот так?

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block')
blocks.forEach((elem, i) => {
    
    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        elem.classList.toggle('active')
    })
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
}

.block {
    flex: 0 1 25%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    border: 2px solid blue
}

.block:last-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.active {
    width: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
    background: #ccc;
    
    height: 600px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Дополнение**

это можно сделать на grid, вот [ссылка на grid generator](https://grid.layoutit.com/), с ним проще будет вникнуть в grid, вот [ссылка на шпаргалку](https://tpverstak.ru/grid/) по grid

Видео уроки по grid

- [CSS Grid: Короткий, Но МОЩНЫЙ Гайд!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnRdT0_8LZQ)
- [CSS Grid Layout. Основные понятия.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV92IdMGFfA)

Вот пример по сайту, который вы скинули, для полного просмотра, разверните код на весь экран. Я постарался сделать даже небольшой адаптив, но стили и структура DOM получилась немного запутанная

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.block-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-template-areas:
    ". . .";
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .block-body {
        flex: 1 1 50%;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .block-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.block-list-first {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "."
    ".";
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .block-list-first {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
    }
}

.block-list-second {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "."
    ".";
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .block-list-second {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
    }
}

.block-list-third {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-template-areas:
    ". .";
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .block-list-third {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}

.block-list-fourth {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "."
    ".";
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .block-list-fourth {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.block-content {
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    background-color: #EBE7E0;
    padding: 80px 20px 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.block-count {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-size: 62px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.block-text {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.block-content img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.red {
    background-color: #C03540;
    color: #fff;
}

.red .block-count {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.block-icon {
    margin-left: 7px;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.block-content:hover .block-icon {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="block-list">
            <div class="block-list-first">
                <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-count">01</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Vision &amp; Value<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/beans.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-count">02</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Community<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/community.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block-list-second">
                <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-count">03</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Metaverse<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/meta3.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-count">04</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Physical World<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/shirts.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block-list-fourth">
            <div class="block-list block-list-third">
                <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-count">05</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Bridge Between<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/bridge.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-count">06</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Seedlings<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/seedlings.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block-body">
                    <div class="block-content red">
                        <p class="block-count">07</p>
                        <p class="block-text">Connect Your Mind<span class="block-icon">→</span></p>
                        <img src="https://www.azuki.com/map/brainwhite.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вот обратная анимация ведет себя как то не так

Comment: `transition: 1s;` укажите только для `.active`

Comment: В таком случае она будет и вовсе отключена

Comment: что-то похожее наткнулся на этот сайт https://www.azuki.com/mindmap но вот как реализовать пока не получается

Comment: https://codepen.io/eugene-kul/pen/WNdXBqY анимация будет только при нажатии

Comment: на сайте https://www.azuki.com/ размеры блоков высчитываются в js, это надо брать размер окна и делить на нужное количество блоков, и задавать каждому элементу нужный вам размер

Comment: Возможно есть где-то примеры подобного решения?

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: спасибо вам, подскажите как можно еще анимацию применить такую же?
больше интересует анимация )

Comment: можете сделать такую же логику как у вас, при нажатии делать `position: fixed`, можете добавить библиотеку fancybox и при нажатии на элемент выводить любой HTML в качестве модального окна

Comment: https://codepen.io/suez/pen/rLGvxr нашел неплохой пример, может пригодится)